# Elimination of directory structure in a tar.gz file

Tags: linux, tar

```
$ tar -zcvf archive/test.tar.gz files
```

will give me as below :

```
files/
files/1
files/2
files/3
```

--

```
$ tar -zcvf archive/test.tar.gz -C files .
```

will give me as below :

```
./
./1
./2
./3
```

I am not able to figure out the right tar command for an output as below .

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Have you tried untaring your archive? I think you'll find the files have been tared the way you want.

Comment: yeah , i did , thing is .. I expect the tar.gz to have no "." in its directory structure

Comment: "." just means the files will extract to the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

`tar ... -C files .` already does what you want.

Since `.` refers to the current directory, the file names "`1`" and "`./1`" are exactly the same thing.

With at least GNU *tar*, to completely remove file paths you will have to give the filenames in command line or via `-T`: `tar c ... file1 file2 file3`. This however gives no practical advantage over just having `./file1` in the tarball.